# How to set V4l2 control values while a Gstreamer pipeline is active in C

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing an application in Qt which is using gstreamer to stream image from a webcamera.I am unable to change the default v4l2 controls of the camera.Whenever i am trying to set controls while gstreamer pipeline is run my program is crashing.

Dump of assembler code for function __kernel_vsyscall:
0x0012d420  <+0>:               int    $0x80
0x0012d422  <+2>:               ret
        End of assembler dump.

Comment: Have you tried `gst-launch v4l2src ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink` (if mjpeg stream webcam)? It works on my Ubuntu

Comment: You should be able to change the source using "device" property also. Could you specify which OS you are developing?

Answer (score 0):

Before change any property of any element, you have to set your pipeline state to paused state, or stopped state, and resume the streaming (by setting the pipeline to playing state) after the properties have been changed successfully.

[Here is a link](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html#section-dynamic-changing) about dynamically changing a pipeline.

best regards